# Is there a way to use the glow tag on an item on an Armor Stand without the Armor Stand getting lit

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm just trying to outline a held item without the invisible Armor Stand getting shown. I don't think there is but it's worth a try asking. Is it possible to only let the item on an Armor Stand glow?

Answer (score 1):

You edited your original comment so now I understand that you meant that you should make it a marker. This got fixed now in 1.15.2 pre1 like you said it would in the comments. Now I also realize that you thought I wanted the armorstand to be visible which I don't.

So answer is summon the armorstand as a marker with glowing and only the item on its head will glow.

Answer (score 0):

No. Glowing is a status effect that can only be applied to entities.

There used to be a workaround by summoning a visible regular armour stand without Glowing and item and an invisible "`Marker:1`" armour stand with Glowing and item at the same position, but this no longer works. You can vote for the bug report here: https://bugs.mojang.com/browse/MC-167220

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you mean

Comment: Then ask me about what you don't understand.

Comment: "But you can summon a second armour stand at the same location, give it the item and make it invisible and glowing. Then the first armour stand still wouldn't put its arm forward, but you can just give it a small item so that it does." 

Wouldn't doing this still show the glowing... Glowing works through blocks right

Comment: This has nothing to do with any blocks. You just summon two armour stands in the same location, one glowing and holding an item, one not glowing and not holding an item (or holding a small item).

Comment: I don't think you understand what I mean with my question, but it doesn't matter

Comment: The issue is that invisible entities still glow, so overlapping them wouldn't help.

Comment: Huh, right, that was indeed a fatal flaw in the plan, thanks for pointing that out. Not even `Marker` helps, then the item doesn't glow either. So I guess it is actually impossible.

Comment: The bug will be fixed in the next version: https://bugs.mojang.com/browse/MC-167220